# Bloco de script PHP/HTML/CSS e JAVASCRIPT

Tags: php, javascript, html

Minha pergunta pode ser boba, mas realmente não sei e não consigo achar na net.

Eu gostaria de adicionar em minha aplicação blocos de trechos com script, e nesse bloco o script realça as funções, variáveis e etc, como em um editor mesmo.

Vocês conhecem algum código jquery, javascript que faz isso? Ou o nome dessa funcionalidade.

Sei que existe a tag `<code>`, mas ela não muda de cor como eu sugeri. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você precisa de um `syntax highlighter`. Existem algumas bibliotecas por aí que executam esta tarefa:

https://highlightjs.org/

http://prismjs.com/

https://craig.is/making/rainbows

Answer (score 4):

Existe como sim. É o plugin Syntax highlighting

Encontrado em https://highlightjs.org/

Espero ter ajudado!